# Is there a way to prevent aiohttp from converting a nested dict that is inside a list in the post form to a string?

Tags: python-3.x, http-post, aiohttp

I am currently writing an api call for a site that has very weird specifics that requires the following type of form data: 
`{"somehting": "something else", "important argument": [{"specific data": "4242", "second data": 0}]}`

But when I formulate the request with `aiohttp.ClientSession()` and test the post request using `https://httpbin.org/` I see that aiohttp is adding a quote to the second dictionary like this: 
`{"somehting": "something else", "important argument": ["{"specific data": "4242", "second data": 0}"]}`
and because of that when I try using the api call the server rejects it with an error.

Is there a way to fix this or should I use a different library?